# Visual Studio 2015 does not install Android SDK for Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am moving towards Xamarin for cross-platform application development. I already had VS2015 installed, I downloaded Xamarin tools(vstoolsforxamarin.exe) from their website and when I install them after a long wait VS says "setup completed with errors"and it does not download and install Android SDK for API 19,20,23, It always say:"Please check your internet connection and try again" and i am sure that my internet connection doesn't get disturbed during all this process. I have tried this 3 times now, tried by uninstalling VS2015, installing it again but got the same error. What is the problem that is causing this? I already have Android Studio installed, with its SDK manager. Any help would be appreciated, that to get Xamarin running in VS2015.

**Edit:**

Solution:
I already had Android Studio and its SDK on my system, going to Tools>Options>Xamarin and giving path of the Android SDK solved my problem.

Comment: I don't think any Visual Studio will install Android SDK for you. Download and install it yourself. Or use the one you got with Android Studio.

Comment: For downloading it , i should be able to make an android project in VS xamarin then i'll able to open SDK manager from it and install whatever i want. Have you tried using Android Studio SDK with it?

Comment: Well here's my solution:
I already had Android Studio and its SDK on my system, going to Tools>Options>Xamarin and giving path of the Android SDK solved my problem. Read this answer on StackOverflow somewhere!

Comment: VS 2015 Enterprise with Update 2 *IS* definetely installing the SDK if you choose Xamarin during setup! I have the same error, no SDK on my system and still don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio installs the SDK @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk 
Either go to that folder and open SDK Manager in administrator mode and install if any new updates are required. 
And in case Visual Studio did not manage to install the SDK, do it manually and change the path for SDK via Tools>Options>Xamarin to the location of SDK.

Comment: @Harry.Naeem You should mark this as the answer then.

Comment: @valdetero i had already edited my question with the solution.

Comment: @Harry.Naeem if an answer answers the question then you should mark it. If none does, then add your own answer and mark it. It helps anyone that comes along later know what solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was proxy-related.

BEFORE installing Visual Studio, create a file at this location:

%USERPROFILE%.android\androidtool.cfg

In the androidtool.cfg file that you just created, place the following contents.  Make sure to update “http.proxyPort” and “http.proxyHost” in the file!

```
### Settings for Android Tool
#Fri Jan 08 02:53:27 UTC 2016
http.proxyPort=8888
sdkman.enable.previews=false
http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
sdkman.ask.adb.restart=false
sdkman.show.update.only=true
sdkman.force.http=false
sdkman.use.dl.cache=true
```

Install Visual Studio normally

Source: http://hauge.cloud/2016/09/22/visual-studio-2015-install-failures-android-sdk-setup-behind-a-proxy/

Comment: In my case, I entered the menu Tools> Options ... and in the Proxy field it showed IP 127.0.0.1 and port 8888. What I did was delete that data. Leave the option "Use download cache" and "Enable Preview Tools" checked, and the rest of checkboxes unchecked. It worked. Additional link http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/6588/how-to-install-android-sdk-without-internet-connection/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found out it was because I did not have enough disk space. I didn't find this out until I manually ran SDK Manager.exe, set my proxy settings, and tried to download a number of SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable my security software (Avast) as it saw it as a potential threat and sandboxed it (Android SDK). After doing that, the software installed flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have jdk installed